# How to pass info between 3 viewcontrollers?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to have a set up where info is passed between viewControllers as follows: 1->2->3->2. Currently I have a set up to pass info from VC 
1->2. The info being passed is the indexPath that a cell is selected from a table. The info needs to be passed because the code in the 2nd viewController' `viewDidLoad()` depends on the cell selected. It is set up as follows (and works fine):
VC 1:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == "cellSelected" else {return}
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let rowSelectedd = indexPath
        let destViewController: MainPageCellSelectedViewController = segue.destination as! MainPageCellSelectedViewController
        destViewController.rowSelected = rowSelectedd!
    }
    var rowSelectedd = IndexPath()
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "cellSelected", sender: rowSelectedd)
    }
```

VC 2 (using the info that is passed):
var rowSelected = IndexPath() //this has info prepared for from the MainPageVC

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if rowSelected.section == 0{
        //do something
    } else{
        // do something else
    }
}
```

In this 2nd viewController there is a button that segues to a third viewController (this also works fine). However, in that *third* viewController there is a back button that segues back to the 2nd viewController. The problem is, the 2nd viewController's `viewDidLoad()` code depends on the variable that was passed from the 1st VC. Since it isn't being passed (because the segue is now from 3->2 instead of 1->2) the app crashes. I am not sure what is the best way to transfer this info appropriately. How should it be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really use segues to navigate backwards unless you're using an Unwind segue. From what you described, it sounds like delegation is what you want.

Try something like this:

```
protocol ThirdVCDelegate {
    func somethingHappens()
}

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue:UIStoryboardSegue, 
                                   sender: Any?) 
    {
        if segue.identifier == "whatever the segue is between second and third VC" {
            let thirdVC = segue.destination as! ThirdVC
            thirdVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

extension SecondVC: ThirdVCDelegate {
    func somethingHappens() {
        // Do whatever you want in SecondVC in response to some action in ThirdVC
    }
}

class ThirdVC: UIViewController {
    var delegate:ThirdVCDelegate!

    func someMethodWhereYouWantToMakeACallbacktoSecondVC {
       delegate.somethingHappens()
       // You can pop or dismiss your thirdVC if you're done with it here.
    }
}
```

You can also add parameters to the protocol method if you want to pass a specific value from thirdVC to secondVC.

Comment: Also highly recommend reading up on delegation in iOS if you haven't done so already because you'll be using it often in development.